# How to realize the hard delete function in Python Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a User realization class, in there I want to have two type delete function:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True) # nickname
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18)  # telephone
    ...
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default=1)


    def soft_del(self):
        self.status = 4
        return True

    def hard_delete_user(self):
        # what should I do there?
        return True
```

you see, one is soft delete a user, the other is hard delete a user.

I mean the soft delete, a user still in the database, but I will not query it by my code, the hard delete is delete it from the database table.

How to realize the `hard_delete_user` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just [**`self.delete()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete), given I understood you correctly:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    # ...

    def hard_delete_user(self):
        self.delete()
        return True
```

You might want to restrict this function, for example only delete the `User` object, given it was already softly deleted, like:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    # ...

    def hard_delete_user(self):
        # example: restrict deletion to softly deleted
        if self.status == 4:
            self.delete()
            return True
        return False
```